# loading content in div from other html file one by one

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to divide my page in two parts. say `div 1` and `div 2`. I want to load first `div` when clicked on the page link. and when contents in `div 1` is fully loaded then I want to start load the content in `div 2`.

Any possible solution that works fine in all major browsers.

I also want the content in these `divs` from other html in the same directory. Below is the code what I tried to do the thing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#div1').load('home/index.html', function() {
        $("#div2").load('home/index2.html');
    });
});
```

I want that when the content from 'home/index.html' is fully loaded in div1 then content from 'home/index2.html' start loading in div2.

Below code is displaying contents in both `div` but I want to start loading in second `div` when my first `div` is completely loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#div1').load('home/index.html');
    $("#div2").load('home/index2.html');
});
```

Comment: your solution seems fine to me, are you facing any issue with it

Comment: yes. it is loading the contents in first div but not loading the contents in second div.

Comment: make sure the `index2.html` is placed at the location where you are trying to access it, also try loading `index.html` in both the divs see if that works

Comment: no your code is perfectly working, may be problem with your index or index2 file

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071838/jquery-load-and-call-function-after-loaded-content-is-rendered

Comment: Yup, your code seems fine and should work.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/7Gnzz/.  There must be something else going on.  Can you check in Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug to see if the second div is populating, and maybe just not displaying for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('#div1').load('home/index.html',function(responseTxt,statusTxt) {
        if(statusTxt == 'success')
        {
            $('#div1').html(responseTxt);
            $('#div2').load('home/index2.html');
        }    

    });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

The callback function of `.load()` is to indicate **load was performed** not ***load is complete***

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is
>   fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set
>   to each DOM element in turn.